# Cannot use dotcover with VS2017 (tests are inconclusive)

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, nunit, resharper, dotcover

I am able to run and debug my unit tests using ReSharper but when I try to use dotcover all tests show as inconclusive.

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (v15.9.4) with ReSharper Ultimate 2018.3, and sll the projects in my solution use .NET Framework 4.7.2.

My unit test project uses NUnit and has the following nuget packages installed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Faker.Net" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="FluentAssertions" version="5.5.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeCoverage" version="15.9.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" version="15.9.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="NBuilder" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.11.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.12.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="RazorEngine" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

These are some of my settings related to tests:

**Unit Testing (General)**

[image: Unit Testing (General) settings]

**Unit Testing (Test Runner)**

[image: Test Runner settings]

Dotcover (General)

[image: Dotcover (General) settings]

What I am missing here?

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio code coverage? Could you please try to uninstall Microsoft.CodeCoverage NuGet package?

Comment: @EkaterinaSolovova I've uninstalled nuget packages `Microsoft.CodeCoverage` and `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` from the unit test project. After that I cleared nuget cache and did a clean/rebuild solution. Unfortunately it didn't make any difference